# Netlogo Cars Merging

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a simulation of a one lane road merging with a two lane road, all going the same direction. The cars that are not merging (cars1) check for merging cars within a radius of 2 to see if they need to change into the left lane and if they do, the car checks the left lane to see if it is safe.

```
ask cars1[
   if (not any? turtles-at -2 4) and (not any? turtles-at -1 4) 
   and (not any? turtles-at 0 4) and (not any? turtles-at 1 4) 
   and (not any? turtles-at 2 4) and (not any? turtles-at 3 4) 
   and (any? merging-cars in-radius 3)
   [  set ycor 2]]
```

I am trying to make the merging cars stop if it is not safe for the cars1 in the closest lane to change to the left lane.

```
ask merging-cars[
  loop[
  if[any? cars1 in-radius 2]
  [stop]
  ]]
```

That is the code that is not working. I haven't figured out a way to make the merging cars stop if it is unsafe and go when it is safe.

Thanks

Comment: Have you had a look at the "Traffic 2 Lanes" model in the model library? It might serve as an example of merging behaviour- cars in the model do not crash, but will only change lanes if there is room in the lane they're trying to enter.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at it and it has helped a lot in certain parts of my simulation but it does not help in this situation.  I need the merging cars to check to see if it is safe, and if it not, they need to stop and wait until it is safe to merge.

Comment: Right. Could you edit your question to include a reproducible example (as in the [MCVE guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? There are several ways to do what you need, but without seeing more detail and context it's difficult to suggest the best option.

Answer (score 0):

To get you on the right direction have a look at the not any? documentation and make a note that you can incorporate the angle of which to check as well as right or left with a command such as :

```
not any? turtles-on patch-right-and-ahead 60 2
```

this is saying.... check the angle of 60 degrees to the right 2 patch ahead of this turtle.